# Multinomial logistic regression analysis or binary logistic regression

Tags: multiple-regression, latent-class

I need to analyse data and am unsure whether or not I should use a multinomial logistic regression analysis or a binary logistic regression analysis. I have just conducted a latent class analysis and am interested in seeing if my variables can predict class membership. There are only two classes and so my response variable only has two categories; however the variables range from having 2 to 3 to 4 and are mostly nominal categorical data.

Comment: Thank you so much that is really helpful. I have started on my analysis but have come to another road block. How should I go about investigating multicollinearity between my independent variables when they are all categorical. Is it ok to just investigate this by running a linear regression and investigating the VIF values?

Comment: I really appreciate your help thank you very much. I have asked another question and was wondering would you be able to provide any solutions? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142513/multicollinearity-in-binary-logistic-regression-analysis-after-latent-class-anal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, if a model's *outcome variable* has only two categories, then the appropriate term for the analysis is *binary logistic regression*, regardless of the number and type of predictors. For details on performing actual *logistic regression analysis*, please see links in my [recent related CV answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142502/31372) as well as [this tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm), [this chapter](http://www.sjsu.edu/people/james.lee/courses/JS203/s1/Online_3.pdf) (SPSS examples) and [this nice set of slides](http://www.columbia.edu/~so33/SusDev/Lecture_10.pdf) (Stata examples).

In regard to potential *multicollinearity*, if you're not familiar with this topic, I suggest you start by reading [corresponding Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity). Also, check some CV discussions, for example [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/87212/31372), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26167/31372) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4854/31372). If you have access to paywalled peer-review journals through your institution, you might want to check [this paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09720502.2010.10700699) and [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21996075). [This blog post](http://learnitdaily.com/six-ways-to-address-collinearity-in-regression-models) presents some options on dealing with collinearity. More details and references on the topic of multicollinearity in general (not specific to logistic regression models) can be found in [my recent relevant answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141613/31372). I hope that this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do realise that it is of importance to know when you have more than two outcomes, if the outcomes are ordered or unordered. In your case (class membership y/n) I don't understand how you can have 3 outcomes unless outcomes 3 and 4 are for instance nested on another property. In this case you can create new variables using for instance excel with an if-statement in which you say if your variable has option 3 or 4 it represents a one and zero otherwise. After this you can use binary logistic regression.

Comment: I have actually overcome that problem but am facing another huge one. Do you have a background in stats and can you help me?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142513/multicollinearity-in-binary-logistic-regression-analysis-after-latent-class-anal